# How to select a table from Wikipedia in jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to write an application in java, that uses information obtained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Switzerland. Specifically, I need a list of cities in Switzerland, which I have to extract from the table in the link. I need to use Jsoup to do it, but I am having some trouble doing that. Specifically, my program cannot "see" or select this specific table. I've tried several methods, and spent hours trying to figure it out, to no avail. I have managed to select the tables in the bottom of the page, about "Switzerland articles" and "List of cities in europe", with

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Switzerland").get();
Elements table = doc.select("table");
```

but, for some reason, it seems to "skip" the table I'm looking for. (The array has seemingly empty tables for table[0] - table[2], and table[3] is the "Switzerland articles" one.) The "Copy selector" option Chrome gives me did not work either, as the output was an size=0 array, and I got a null pointer exception from it when trying to parse it. I am very new to HTML and Jsoup, and cannot understand where my problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this selector -

```
doc.select(".wikitable");
```

Use also the `User Agent` string that matches your browser, to make sure you get the same result in your browser and in your application, like this -

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Switzerland")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0")
            .get();
Elements table = doc.select(".wikitable");
```

Comment: You should be using more restrictive content. ".wikitable" select any table so as the wikipedia page might be updated (as it really useally is), if any table is added it will break.

Comment: The code works. The application does what I want it to do, though I do agree with what @Cukic0d said. It works for this project, and I doubt there'll be another table soon enough to matter in the current project, but indeed, the solution is not perfect. That said, of course, I am confident I could make it work around that. My problem was mostly the null Element I was getting in return, not choosing between the returned tables.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
doc.select("div.mw-content-text > table.wikitable");
```

It should work according to the doc page of jsoup:
https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

You can look further in it :)

Comment: Well you can look at the doc :)

Comment: Accidentally removed my comment. Anyways, the code by TDG worked.

Comment: I had already tried something similar to it, hence why I was "pretty sure" I'd tried it, and it did not work. And what I had tried, just as your solution, should work, according to the documentation. That is what had baffled me. Thanks anyway. :)